# Turn vehicle off then on again and the right blinker is automatically on switch wasnt on when i switched car off

Tags: nissan, cel, control

I turn my car on and then the right blinker is switched on . Why is that and the dash flashes aswell.
It wasnt on when turned ignition off and the engine light is on aswell but still not flasing nissan  stagea 1996

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please enlighten us as to what the year/make/model of the car you are asking about is?

Comment: 1996 nissan stagea

Comment: How do you turn it off in centre position?

Comment: There could be loose or worn parts in the steering column. Don't forget, the ignition switch movement also operates the steering wheel lock.